# How to fix the quiz countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone or anyone please help me to fix the quiz countdown timer. The problem is the quiz countdown timer is stuck to question #1, if the user is not answered it will be go to the next questions. And also the Submit & Next button I can't click it after I answered the question it will be go to the next questions too. Where codes I should fix, please help.

[quiz preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RSD1.png)

Here's my quiz_php

```
<?php
$quiz_questions = $this->crud_model->get_quiz_questions($lesson_details['id']);
?>

<div id="quiz-body">
    <div class="" id="quiz-header">
        <?php echo get_phrase("quiz_title"); ?> : <strong><?php echo $lesson_details['title']; ?></strong><br>
        <?php echo get_phrase("number_of_questions"); ?> : <strong><?php echo count($quiz_questions->result_array()); ?></strong><br>
        <?php if (count($quiz_questions->result_array()) > 0): ?>
            <button id="start_page" type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-sign-up mt-2" style="color: #fff;" onclick="getStarted(1)"><?php echo get_phrase("get_started"); ?></button>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <form class="" id="quiz_form" action="" method="post">
        <?php if (count($quiz_questions->result_array()) > 0): ?>
            <?php foreach ($quiz_questions->result_array() as $key => $quiz_question):
                $options = json_decode($quiz_question['options']);
            ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="<?php echo $lesson_details['id']; ?>">

                <div class="hidden" id = "question-number-<?php echo $key+1; ?>">

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                            <div class="card text-left">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo get_phrase("question").' '.($key+1); ?> : <strong><?php echo $quiz_question['title']; ?></strong></h6>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($options as $key2 => $option): ?>
                                    <li class="list-group-item quiz-options">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $quiz_question['id']; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $key2+1; ?>" 
                                            id="quiz-id-<?php echo $quiz_question['id']; ?>-option-id-<?php echo $key2+1; ?>" onclick="enableNextButton('<?php echo $quiz_question['id'];?>')">
                                            
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="quiz-id-<?php echo $quiz_question['id']; ?>-option-id-<?php echo $key2+1; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $option; ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="justify-content-end"  style="float: right; margin: 5px 0px 40px 40px;">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body" id="clock">    
                                        <h5 class="text-right m-1"> Quiz Time: 00:<span class="" id="time">00</span></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-sign-up mt-2 mb-2" id="next-btn-<?php echo $quiz_question['id'];?>" 
                    style="color: #fff;" <?php if(count($quiz_questions->result_array()) == $key+1):?>
                    onclick="submitQuiz()"<?php else: ?>onclick="showNextQuestion('<?php echo $key+2; ?>')"<?php endif; ?> disabled>
                    <?php echo count($quiz_questions->result_array()) == $key+1 ? get_phrase("check_result") : get_phrase("submit_&_next"); ?></button>

                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="quiz-result" class="text-left">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Quiz with Countdown Timer

function getStarted(first_quiz_question) {
    $('#quiz-header').hide();
    $('#lesson-summary').hide();
    $('#question-number-'+first_quiz_question).show();


    var timer = 30;                 // Time counter
    var quiz_questionsCount = 0;   // Questions counter

    // Questions array
    var questions = 'quiz_form';

    questionDivId = document.getElementById('start_page');

    setInterval(function () {
        timer--;

        if (timer >= 0) {
            id = document.getElementById('time');
            id.innerHTML = timer;
        }
        if (timer === 0) {
            id.innerHTML = alert('Time is over. Next Question...');
            timer = 30;
            quiz_questionsCount++;
        }

        // To check if all questions are completed or not will be show the quiz result
        if (quiz_questionsCount === questions.length){
            questionDivId.innerHTML = alert('Your time has finally over. It seems some of your quiz has not been answered.');
            id.innerHTML = "";

            function submitQuiz() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('home/submit_quiz'); ?>',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('form#quiz_form').serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#quiz-body').hide();
                        $('#quiz-result').html(response);
                    }

                });

            }

        } else{
            questionDivId.innerHTML = questions[quiz_questionsCount];
        }
    }, 1000)

    // To go to the next question
    function showNextQuestion(next_question) {
        $('#question-number-'+(next_question-1)).show();
        $('#question-number-'+next_question).show();
        quiz_questionsCount++;
        timer = 30;
    }

}

function submitQuiz() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('home/submit_quiz'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form#quiz_form').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#quiz-body').hide();
            $('#quiz-result').html(response);
        }

    });

}

function enableNextButton(quizID) {
    $('#next-btn-'+quizID).prop('disabled', false);

}

</script>
```

I am expecting the result of quiz with the quiz countdown timer works perfectly if the user is answered it will pause the time (example 25secs) then user click next button it will be go to the next questions where the timer will continue last timer and so on. And if the user is not answered or away from keyboard it will show alert message the 'Time is over' it will be disabled the question's choices, user will go to the next questions.

Comment: can you remove the extra code from sample and just put the logic which you are using for timer.

Comment: I think its done but I need to know where are the codes connected to quiz countdown timer in the javascript. @Ankitdagar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you are using setInterval() in js to calculate the time which is not accurate and data/timer is deemed to fail at time point in time, i would recommend to do it with date-time use below function to get time diff and call it insude setInterval so that values doesn't get effected by language.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(expire) {
    var t = utcDate(new Date(Date.parse(expire))) - utcDate(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

var expire = "<?php echo $exp; ?>";
getTimeRemaining(expire);
```

Comment: Can you enlighten me how do I put it inside javascript is it inside the functions ?